# Empty analysis of projects after upgrade to sonarqube 4.0

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

After sonar upgrade from 3.5.1 to sonarqube 4.0, all the Soanr projects analysis become blank.

I am unable to create the sonar-project.properties file on the project root folder, so instead I created linux **soft-link** to the source code and located it on the project.properties file directory.

This configuration worked perfectly before the upgrade, but now, on the analysis log I get WARN messages such bellow to all of the source files:

```
20:58:13.290 WARN  - File '/asthome/ast/ccast/mb_ccast/bb/ccrm9Client/v79_9/com/astro/crm/cim/desktop/XNoLinkedWebAccount.java' is not in basedir '/asthome/ast/ccast/sonar/sonar/crm'
```

I am using sonar-runner 2.3. 
Can you please help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

What I was done in order to solve the issue in my case was to add to my sonar-project.properties file
a property named: 
`sonar.modules="module1"` 
 This was allowed me to change the base directory of the module
with the property
 
`module1.sonar.projectBaseDir=path to my base dir` 
I also needed to changed my source and binaries properties names to

`module1.sonar.sources=<source folder>` 
 
`module1.sonar.binaries=<build folder>`

After this change I was able to analysis my source code without issues. 
(No links is needed now...)

I hope it will solved your issue too

Comment: I've just encountered the same problem. sonar-runner 2.3, SonarQube 4.0.
I get the same warning "WARN - File 'path/to/file' is not in basedir '../bin'". I have an instance of 3.5 Sonar. I will try it now.

Comment: Still a bit of a workaround, but it should do what I intend to.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar setup, Sonar-Runner is executed in a sub-directory of the project-tree, sources are spread outside of the directory where sonar is running.

The only solution that I found is to actually copy the source and test-files into the current directory and using this as source-directories for Sonar.

Works, but causes additional copying/deleting of files without an actual reason why this is necessary.

BTW: For binary files it seems to be possible to have them in other directories.